# running pronterface in python: import error: no module named

Tags: python, interface, module, importerror

I am a complete beginner to programming, python, pronterface and 3d printing so unsurprisingly I am having a few difficulties.

I have now managed to download pronterface and get it running on my computer, i think i followed the download instructions correctly and have skeinforge downloaded also in the printrun folder.

My problem is that when I try to open or load a .stl file I get the following:

```
Skeining C:\Users\James\Downloads\70mm_Faberdashery_Yoda-Lite_less_robe.stl
Skeinforge execution failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\3d printer software\pronterface\Printrun-d482c66\pronterface.py", line 940, in skein_func
    from skeinforge.skeinforge_application.skeinforge_utilities import skeinforge_craft
ImportError: No module named skeinforge_application.skeinforge_utilities
```

However the file is in the right place I think:

```
C:\Users\James\Desktop\3dp\pronterface\Printrun-d482c66\skeinforge\skeinforge application\skeinforge utilities\skeinforge_craft
```

Can you try to explain in plain language any ideas to fix this as I am a total beginner and don't even really know what a module import error is.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the reprap forms was having a [similar issue](http://forums.reprap.org/read.php?154,128581,128581,quote=1), the recommendation there is to run skeinforge from the command line.

To solve the problem more satisfactorily, you'd need to check what path is available to python and make sure that the path to the skeinforge module is in your system path or the python path.